# tag with <br> count as empty?

Tags: html, css

Does a tag like this count as empty when forexample doing this?

**HTML**

```
 <p>
    </br>
    </p>
```

**CSS**
p:empty {display:none}

Comment: Well, have you actually *tried* what you are asking..?

Comment: Did you look up CSS `:empty` and see what it is meant to select? Did you try the code and see if it works?

Comment: Well, I tried and it didn't seem to work, so I just wanted to double-check it.

Comment: My gut feeling says that with the error, different browsers will handle this differently (some will discard the bad end tag and treat the p as empty, others won't). Edit: then again, Lance its right and even the whitespace makes the p not-empty, so the bad end tag doesn't matter. Oh well.

Comment: See my code below.  It won't even be seen as empty when the opening and closing P tags are on different lines.  In IE and Chrome at least.

Comment: Thx, I got a little bit wiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For

```
p:empty {display:none}
```

to apply the p must actually be empty.

```
<p></p>
```

is empty and will take the style.

```
<p>
</p>
```

is NOT empty and will not take the style.

In the code below the border is added for illustration purposes only.

```css
p { border: 1px solid red; }
p:empty { display:none }
```

```html
<p></p>

<p>
</p>
```

Comment: Any ideas how to hide objects that only contain a `<br>` inside?

Comment: No, not really.  You might need javascript for that.  You could post it as a new question though.  You might get some elegant and creative answers.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. The :empty pseudo selector will select elements that contain either nothing or only an HTML comment.

```
<div></div>
<div><br/></div>
```

and

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
div:empty {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

So here you will see only first div having border blue and second having border red.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n988rhy0/)